# Javascript form validating - how do you show validation errors in a single table rather than using alerts

Tags: javascript

I am new to .asp and Javascript and wondered if someone was able to advise how to show validation errors for fields below the form in a single table or text field rather than using alerts. Alerts and validation are working.

Here is the table that i plan to put the validation errors into:

```html
<asp:Table ID="StatusTable" 
            runat="server" Width="100%"><asp:TableRow ID="StatusRow" runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell ID="StatusTextCell" runat="server" Width="95%">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="StatusTextBox" runat="server" Width="100%" />
                </asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell ID="StatusPadCell" runat="server" Width="5%">
                    &nbsp;
                </asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow></asp:Table>
```

And here is an example of some the Javascript I am using where i need the validation error messages to show in the table rather than from alerts.

Would be extremely grateful for any advise

```js
< script type = "text/javascript"
language = "Javascript" >
  function RequiredTextValidate() {
    //check all required fields from Completed Table are returned
    if (document.getElementById("<%=CompletedByTextBox.ClientID%>").value == "") {
      alert("Completed by field cannot be blank");
      return false;
    }

    if (document.getElementById("<%=CompletedExtTextBox.ClientID %>").value == "") {
      alert("Completed By Extension field cannot be blank");
      return false;
    }

    if (document.getElementById("<%=EmployeeNoTextBox.ClientID %>").value == "") {
      alert("Employee No field cannot be blank");
      return false;
    }

    if (document.getElementById("<%=EmployeeNameTextBox.ClientID %>").value == "") {
      alert("Employee Name field cannot be blank");
      return false;

    }
    return true;
  }

< /script>
```

```js
function ValidateFields() {
            //Validate all Required Fields on Form
       
            if (RequiredTextValidate() && CheckDate(document.getElementById("<%=SickDateTextBox.ClientID%>").value) && CheckTime(this) && ReasonAbsent() && ReturnDateChanged() && FirstDateChanged() && ActualDateChanged() == true) {
                    return true; 
                }
                else
                return false;
        }
```

Comment: Would be extremely grateful if someone could please advise on the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways that this type of thing can be done, here is one way which I have put together based on what you have so far...

http://jsfiddle.net/c0nh2rke/

```js
function RequiredTextValidate() {
    var valMessage = '';
    var valid = true;
    //check all required fields from Completed Table are returned
    if (document.getElementById("test1").value == "") {
        valMessage += 'Completed by field cannot be blank <br />';
      valid = false;
    }

    if (document.getElementById("test2").value == "") {
        valMessage += 'Completed By Extension field cannot be blank <br />';
      valid = false;
    }

    if (document.getElementById("test3").value == "") {
        valMessage += 'Employee No field cannot be blank <br />';
      valid = false;
    }

    if (document.getElementById("test4").value == "") {
        valMessage += 'Employee Name field cannot be blank <br />';
      valid = false;

    }
    if (valid) {
    return true;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("errors").innerHTML = valMessage;
        return false;
    }
  }
```

```html
<form >
<input id="test1" type="text" /><br />
<input id="test2" type="text" /><br />
<input id="test3" type="text" /><br />
<input id="test4" type="text" /><br />
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="RequiredTextValidate()" />
</form>
<div id="errors"><div>
```

HTML

```
<form >
<input id="test1" type="text" /><br />
<input id="test2" type="text" /><br />
<input id="test3" type="text" /><br />
<input id="test4" type="text" /><br />
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="RequiredTextValidate()" />
</form>
<div id="errors"><div>
```

Script

```
function RequiredTextValidate() {
    var valMessage = '';
    var valid = true;
    //check all required fields from Completed Table are returned
    if (document.getElementById("test1").value == "") {
        valMessage += 'Completed by field cannot be blank <br />';
      valid = false;
    }

    if (document.getElementById("test2").value == "") {
        valMessage += 'Completed By Extension field cannot be blank <br />';
      valid = false;
    }

    if (document.getElementById("test3").value == "") {
        valMessage += 'Employee No field cannot be blank <br />';
      valid = false;
    }

    if (document.getElementById("test4").value == "") {
        valMessage += 'Employee Name field cannot be blank <br />';
      valid = false;

    }
    if (valid) {
    return true;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("errors").innerHTML = valMessage;
        return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for info but how would i link these field inputs to the 4 i have already created ? E.g Test 1 would need to correspond with "<%=CompletedByTextBox.ClientID%>"

Comment: I am also using OnClientClick="return ValidateFields()"/> which is working fine with the alerts

Comment: I used `test4` etc because you did not post your HTML code, only your ASP code which I can not run to create the generated HTML. You should be able to replace them like for like with the ones that you were using already. In your second comment, you said about `OnClientClick`, are you using that along with `onClick` as a way of attaching another method? I would not do that if you are, instead have one method call the other.

Comment: Im using OnClick to generate a Word Document from which the fields are added to so the OnClientClick is being used for the validation of the fields. I am also validating a number of functions rather than one but it is working.

Comment: if you take a look in my `if (valid)` block, I just `return true`. You can easily call a new method there instead. So first call your validation, if it valid then have that call your Word Doc etc. If you attach multiple events with different handlers like you are, they will all run and you will have invalid forms being submitted.

Comment: Ive now got this working using a DIV and adding a <BR> to format my error messages. Thanks for your help wf4

Answer (score 0):

The best JavaScript is no JavaScript.

To that end, consider:

```html
<form action="javascript:alert('Submitted!');" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="someinput" placeholder="Type something!" required />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit form" />
</form>
```

Notice how the browser will render native UI to show that the field was left blank? This is by far the best way to do it because it doesn't rely on JavaScript. Not that there's anything wrong with JS, mind, but far too often a single typo in form validation code has caused hours of debugging!

Comment: Will this only work in certain browsers? I'm using IE11 and I do not get anything when I leave the field blank.